# Grails f:table customization

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am trying to use template to apply to my scaffolding of f:table. However I do not know how to access the information of each line of my table in order to properly write my template. For simple fields, I have bean, property,label, and such but I cannot find any documentation pointing out how to access information for f:table. Please help me out guys !
Grails 3.1.x

Comment: Is it about Field Plugin, https://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/guide/index.html? If yes, then I don't see `f:table`

Comment: here is the link to the f:table https://grails3-plugins.github.io/fields/snapshot/ref/Tags/table.html the f:table is automatically generated when scaffolding the index view.

Answer (score 5):

See, if this sample below can provide you some hint.

```
<table>
    <thead>
         <tr>
            <g:each in="${domainProperties}" var="p" status="i">
                <g:set var="propTitle">
                    ${domainClass.propertyName}.${p.name}.label
                </g:set>
                <g:sortableColumn property="${p.name}" 
                                  title="${message(code: propTitle, default: p.naturalName)}" />
            </g:each>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <g:each in="${collection}" var="bean" status="i">
            <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                <g:each in="${domainProperties}" var="p" status="j">
                    <g:if test="${j==0}">
                        <td>
                            <g:link method="GET" resource="${bean}">
                                <f:display bean="${bean}" 
                                           property="${p.name}" 
                                           displayStyle="${displayStyle?:'table'}" />
                            </g:link>
                        </td>
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <td>
                            <f:display bean="${bean}" 
                                       property="${p.name}"  
                                       displayStyle="${displayStyle?:'table'}"/>
                        </td>
                    </g:else>
                </g:each>
            </tr>
        </g:each>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Taken from [the Github page](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/fields/blob/master/grails-app/views/templates/_fields/_table.gsp).

Comment: I'm using Grails 4.0.1. The latest template from Github gives me "Error evaluating expression [domainClass.propertyName] on line [6]: No such property: propertyName for class: org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernatePersistentEntity" I've been searching all over for a solution to this, but have not found one.

Comment: @lurker: Grails 4.0.x is very different. I doubt, if Grails 3 plugins will work there. See if this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210863/no-such-property-propertyname-for-class-org-grails-orm-hibernate-cfg-hibernate , helps.

Comment: I was finding that out! And unfortunately, that question doesn't help, either. The answer there doesn't really even answer the OP's question  aI worked around the error with a hack, and then encountered a similar error later in the template. All of the latest official plugin information online seems to apply to Grails 3.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation for this plugin is a bit sketchy. The part you are looking for is in section [Customizing Field Rendering](https://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/snapshot/guide/index.html#customizingFieldRendering).

The particular table you are looking for (containing `value`, `bean`, etc. parameters) is called *Template parameters*.